# How to use subclassed class in qt

Tags: qt

I've subclassed qt's pushbutton and now I would like to use it in my project (instead of qpushbutton) - the problem I have is that even if I add #include "mybutton.h" in ui_class it gets overwritten and I don't know what else can I do it.
Is there a way to have this button within designer on a panel just like the ordinary qpushbutton is?

Answer (score 3):

Never modify the ui_Class file yourself. Any change you make there will be overwritten when the .ui gets compiled. Instead use the [promote to](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-using-custom-widgets.html) functionality within QtDesigner.

> If some forms must be designed, but certain custom widgets are
>   unavailble to the designer, we can substitute similar widgets to
>   represent the missing widgets. For example, we might represent
>   instances of a custom push button class, MyPushButton, with instances
>   of QPushButton and promote these to MyPushButton so that uic generates
>   suitable code for this missing class.

Comment: @webcletic ok, thanks I did as you've suggested. Now I have another problem. I've implemented signal clicked(QString) and I  connected it to the line edit slot set_text(QString), but I don't know how to pass the text on the button as this QString obj. Would you know how to do it?

Comment: You cannot connect a signal to a slot if the signatures do not match. Check the [corresponding documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots-with-default-arguments) for more details. You should connect the signal clicked() with an empty slot and then from this slot call the setText function of the button. However you should close this question and start a new one

Comment: @weblectic but the signatures do match clicked(QString) in my button and set_text(QString) in qlineedit

Comment: The default clicked signal of QPushButton has a bool argument and not a QString one. If this is a signal of your own subclass then it does not make sense to have a QString argument. In any way you have to emit it explicitly from the implementation of your push button

Comment: You could connect the button to it's own clicked() signal. Then in a slot handling this signal, you can re-emit your own clicked(QString) signal.

Comment: However, what you probably want to do is just connect clicked() to an empty slot, as webclectic suggested. Then from there call `mylineedit->setText( qobject_cast<QAbstractButton *>( sender() )->text() )`. IF that's what you want to achieve...